# Indicator feature creation in R based on multiple columns

Tags: r, feature-extraction

I have a dataset with 10 columns and out of them 10, 3 are of interest to create a new indicator feature. The features are "pT", "pN", & "M" and they all take different values. Off all the values that these 3 features take, there are a toal of 9 unique combinations that needs to be captures in the new variable.

```
   PATHOT PATHON PATHOM
1       pT2    pN1     M0
4       pT1    pN1     M0
13      pT3    pN1     M0
161     pT1   *pN2     M0
391     pT1    pN1    *M1
810   *pTIS    pN1     M0
948     pT3   *pN2     M0
1043    pT2    pN1    *M1
1067   *pT4    pN1     M0
```

For example, the new variable will have value "1" when PATHOT=pT2, PATHON=pN1 & PATHOM=M0 and so on upto value 9. I have completed the task but after spending almost 20 lines of code involving vectorised operation for all unique combinations.

```
diag3_bs$sfd[diag3_bs$pathot=="pT2" & diag3_bs$pathon=="pN1" & 
               diag3_bs$pathom=="M0"] <- 1
diag3_bs$sfd[diag3_bs$pathot=="pT1" & diag3_bs$pathon=="pN1" & 
               diag3_bs$pathom=="M0"] <- 2
diag3_bs$sfd[diag3_bs$pathot=="pT3" & diag3_bs$pathon=="pN1" & 
               diag3_bs$pathom=="M0"] <- 3... so on upto 9.
```

I want to ask if there is a better more automated way of getting the same result?

`dput(data.frame)` is given below

```
 structure(list(F_STATUS = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L,
 1L, 1L), .Label = "Y", class = "factor"), EVENT_ID = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BASELINE", class =
 "factor"), 
     PAG_NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
     1L), .Label = "BR2", class = "factor"), PTSIZE = c(3, 4, 
     2.7, 2, 0.9, 3, 3, 0.9, 3, 4.5), PTSIZE_U = structure(c(1L, 
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CM", class = "factor"), 
     PT_SYM = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
     1L), .Label = c("", "-", "<", ">"), class = "factor"), PATHOT = structure(c(4L, 
     4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("*pT4", "*pTIS", 
     "pT1", "pT2", "pT3"), class = "factor"), PATHON = structure(c(2L, 
     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("*pN2", "pN1"
     ), class = "factor"), PATHOM = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("*M1", "M0"), class = "factor"), 
     RSUBJID = 901000:901009, RUSUBJID = structure(1:10, .Label = c(
     "000301-000-901-251", "000301-000-901-252", "000301-000-901-253", 
     "000301-000-901-254", "000301-000-901-255", "000301-000-901-256", 
     "000301-000-901-257", "000301-000-901-258", "000301-000-901-259", 
     "000301-000-901-260", "000301-000-901-261", "000301-000-901-262")
, class = "factor")), .Names = c("F_STATUS",  "EVENT_ID", "PAG_NAME", "PTSIZE", "PTSIZE_U", "PT_SYM", "PATHOT", 
 "PATHON", "PATHOM", "RSUBJID", "RUSUBJID"), row.names = c(NA,  10L),
 class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to edit the data so it didn't throw an error on input. Also created a version of that tabulation of possible combinations:

```
stg_tbl <- structure(list(PATHOT = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 1L), .Label = c("*pT4", "*pTIS", "pT1", "pT2", "pT3"), class = "factor"), 
    PATHON = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("*pN2", 
    "pN1"), class = "factor"), PATHOM = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("*M1", "M0"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("PATHOT", 
"PATHON", "PATHOM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"4", "13", "161", "391", "810", "948", "1043", "1067"))
```

Make a vector of text-equivalents of the categories:

```
stg_lbls <- with(stg_tbl, paste(PATHOT, PATHON, PATHOM, sep="_") )
```

Then the as.numeric values of a factor created using those levels will be the desired result:

```
dat$stg <- with(dat, factor( paste(PATHOT, PATHON, PATHOM, sep="_"), levels=stg_lbls))
as.numeric(dat$stg)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

You can just assign those values in the usual way:

```
dat$sfd <- as.numeric(dat$stg)
```

Answer (score 2):

I made some new data, that should be useful for your problem.

```
k<-expand.grid(data.frame(a=letters[1:3],b=letters[4:6],c=letters[7:9]))
library(dplyr)
k %>% mutate(groups=paste0(a,b,c))->k2
k2$groups<-as.numeric(factor(k2$groups))
k2
```

It's crude, and you're not picking which combination get's which numbers, so it'd take some digging afterwards, but it's quick.